# React JS: How to add multiple placeholder object inside components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object

Sorry this question might be duplicated, but none of the existing answers helped me
I'm a beginner in React and js

I want to add multiple objects inside the component

Like:

```
src={url}
name={text}
subTitle={subtext}
```

> my index.js

```
const tableColumns = [
  {
    title: 'Title/Artist',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
    render: (text) => (
      <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
        <AvatarStatus
          shape="square"
          src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02bd26ede1ae69327010d49946"
          name={text}
          subTitle="Dua Lipa"
        />
      </div>
    ),
  },
];

return (
<>
   <Table 
     className="no-border-last" 
     columns={tableColumns} 
     dataSource={recentReleasesData} 
     rowKey='id' 
     pagination={false}
   />
 </>
```

> my data.js

```
export const RecentReleasesData = [
  {
    id: '#5332',
    artwork: 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02bd26ede1ae69327010d49946',
    name: 'Future Nostalgia',
    artist: 'Dua Lipa',
    label: 'Warner Records',
    barcode: '19029500',
    releasedate: '2021-02-11',
    tracks: '11',
    promolink: 'Smart Link',
    status: 'Approved',
  },
  {
    id: '#6438',
    artwork: 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02caf82abb2338880577e472be',
    name: 'Love',
    artist: 'Someonw',
    label: 'UMG Records',
    barcode: '50029500',
    releasedate: '2017-08-21',
    tracks: '2',
    promolink: 'Smart Link',
    status: 'Rejected',
  },
];
```

> My comp AvatarStatus.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Avatar } from 'antd';

const renderAvatar = props => {
    return <Avatar {...props} className={`ant-avatar-${props.type}`}>{props.text} 
    </Avatar>;
}

export const AvatarStatus = props => {
  const { name, suffix, subTitle, id, type, src, icon, size, shape, gap, text, 
  onNameClick } = props
    return (
      <div className="avatar-status d-flex align-items-center">
        {renderAvatar({icon, src, type, size, shape, gap, text })}
          <div className="ml-2">
            <div>
                {
                  onNameClick ? 
                    <div
                      onClick={() => onNameClick({name, subTitle, src, id})} 
                      className="avatar-status-name clickable">{name}
                    </div> 
                    :
                    <div className="avatar-status-name"><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 
                      {name}</a>
                    </div>
                }
            <span>{suffix}</span>
          </div>
        <div className="text-muted avatar-status-subtitle">{subTitle}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

AvatarStatus.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  src: PropTypes.string,
  type: PropTypes.string,
  onNameClick: PropTypes.func
}


export default AvatarStatus;
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

components are like JavaScript functions. They accept arbitrary inputs (called “props”) and return React elements describing what should appear on the screen.
This function is a valid React component because it accepts a single “props” (which stands for properties) object argument with data and returns a React element. We call such components “function components” because they are literally JavaScript functions.

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/YGYmEG?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

> index.js

```
render: (_, record) => (
  <Flex>
    <AvatarStatus
      shape="square"
      size={50}
      src={record.artwork}
      name={record.title}
      subTitle={record.artist}/>
  </Flex>
),
```